# "auto" keyword affects math calculations?

Tags: c++, auto

Consider next code:

```
#include <cmath>
unsigned int nump=12u;
auto inner=2.5;
auto outer=6.0;
auto single=2*3.14159265359/nump;
auto avg=0.5*inner+0.5*outer;
for (auto i=0u;i<nump;++i){
    auto theta=i*single;
    auto px=avg*sin(theta);
    auto py=avg*cos(theta);
    auto tw=17.;
    int v1=std::round(1+px-tw/2.0);
    int v2=std::round(2+py-tw/2.0);
    std::cout<<"#"<<i<<":"<<v1<<";"<<v2<<std::endl;
}
```

it produces output like this:

```
#0:-8;-2  
#1:-5;-3  
#2:-4;-4  
#3:-3;-7  
#4:-4;-9  
#5:-5;-10  
#6:-8;-11  
#7:-10;-10  
#8:-11;-9  
#9:-12;-6   
#10:-11;-4  
#11:-10;-3
```

Now let's modify this code by replacing most of "auto" with "float":

```
#include <cmath>
unsigned int nump=12u;
float inner=2.5;
float outer=6.0;
float single=2*3.14159265359/nump;
float avg=0.5*inner+0.5*outer;
for (unsigned int i=0u;i<nump;++i){
    float theta=i*single;
    float px=avg*sin(theta);
    float py=avg*cos(theta);
    float tw=17.;
    int v1=std::round(1+px-tw/2.0);
    int v2=std::round(2+py-tw/2.0);
    std::cout<<"#"<<i<<":"<<v1<<","<<v2<<std::endl;
}
```

and here's the second output:

```
#0:-8,-2  
#1:-5,-3  
#2:-4,-4  
#3:-3,-7  
#4:-4,-9  
#5:-5,-10  
#6:-8,-11  
#7:-10,-10  
#8:-11,-9  
#9:-12,-7  
#10:-11,-4  
#11:-10,-3
```

As one can see in line 9 values are different.
Any explanation?
PS. OS X 10.12 c++11 and c++14, Apple LLVM 8.1; however was observed also on linux platform with C++17.

**UPDATE**
As people suggested I modified the code by adding "f" suffix to floating-point values.

```
unsigned int nump=12u;
auto inner=2.5f;
auto outer=6.0f;
auto single=2.f*3.14159265359f/nump;
auto avg=0.5f*inner+0.5f*outer;
for (auto i=0u;i<nump;++i){
    auto theta=i*single;
    auto px=avg*sin(theta);
    auto py=avg*cos(theta);
    auto tw=17.f;
    int v1=std::round(1.f+px-tw/2.0f);
    int v2=std::round(2.f+py-tw/2.0f);
    std::cout<<"#"<<i<<":"<<v1<<";"<<v2<<std::endl;
}
```

versus

```
unsigned int nump=12u;
float inner=2.5f;
float outer=6.0f;
float single=2.f*3.14159265359f/nump;
float avg=0.5f*inner+0.5f*outer;
for (unsigned int i=0u;i<nump;++i){
    float theta=i*single;
    float px=avg*sin(theta);
    float py=avg*cos(theta);
    float tw=17.f;
    int v1=std::round(1.f+px-tw/2.0f);
    int v2=std::round(2.f+py-tw/2.0f);
    std::cout<<"#"<<i<<":"<<v1<<";"<<v2<<std::endl;
}
```

The result is exactly the same.

Comment: Floating-point literals without a suffix are of type `double`. If you want a `float`, write `2.5f`.

Comment: Is that `float` vs `double` selected by `auto`?? `float` literals need to be declared explicitly using `f` as postfix.

Comment: you are using a suffix for `12u`, floating point literals can be of different types too

Answer (score 0):

`2.5` for example is a `double` type. So `inner` is a `double` in your first snippet, but a `float` in the second. (Note that the expression `2 * 3.14159265359 / nump` is a `double` too.)

So the type conversions are bound to cost precision in places. That is the cause of the difference you observe.

On modern desktop systems you'll likely find that `double` is faster than a `float` as in using the latter can cause type conversions (unnoticed by the programmer) at the machine level.

Answer (score 0):

No. `auto` does not directly affect maths. What does affect maths is the type of your variables involved in the calculation.

```
float inner=2.5;
```

This is a `float` initialized by the floating point literal `2.5` which is of type `double`.

This on the other hand:

```
auto inner=2.5;
```

Declares `inner` to be initialized with the floating point literal `2.5` which is of type `double` and the type of `inner` is deduced from the initializer: `innter` is a `double`.

Change your floating point literals to `float` to get the same results. For example `2.5` -> `2.5f`.

---

`auto` does not change the meaning of code when you replace it with the exact type that it gets deduced to. If you replace it with a different type then the meaning of the code is changed.