# Does "auto" keyword always evaluates floating point value as double?

Tags: c++, auto

Continuing the question, which was closed:
[C++: "auto" keyword affects math calculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047832/c-auto-keyword-affects-math-calculations)

As people suggested I modified the code by adding "f" suffix to floating-point values.

```
#include <cmath>
unsigned int nump=12u;
auto inner=2.5f;
auto outer=6.0f;
auto single=2.f*3.14159265359f/nump;
auto avg=0.5f*inner+0.5f*outer;
for (auto i=0u;i<nump;++i){
    auto theta=i*single;
    auto px=avg*sin(theta);
    auto py=avg*cos(theta);
    auto tw=17.f;
    int v1=std::round(1.f+px-tw/2.0f);
    int v2=std::round(2.f+py-tw/2.0f);
    std::cout<<"#"<<i<<":"<<v1<<";"<<v2<<std::endl;
}
```

versus

```
#include <cmath>
unsigned int nump=12u;
float inner=2.5f;
float outer=6.0f;
float single=2.f*3.14159265359f/nump;
float avg=0.5f*inner+0.5f*outer;
for (unsigned int i=0u;i<nump;++i){
    float theta=i*single;
    float px=avg*sin(theta);
    float py=avg*cos(theta);
    float tw=17.f;
    int v1=std::round(1.f+px-tw/2.0f);
    int v2=std::round(2.f+py-tw/2.0f);
    std::cout<<"#"<<i<<":"<<v1<<";"<<v2<<std::endl;
}
```

The result is exactly the same - output differs between two versions.
So does it mean that "auto" always evaluates floating point value to "double" type?

Comment: … no it doesn’t. In the code you’ve posted it evaluates to `float`. More generally, it evaluates to the type *of the initialiser expression*, whatever that is. The type of `2.5` is `double`, the type of `2.5f` is `float`. That’s all there is to it.

Comment: Highly related, if not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048332/does-auto-keyword-always-evaluates-floating-point-value-as-double

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You’ve linked to this question.

Comment: But no matter what suffix I use the result outputs differ in exactly same manner.

Comment: It all boils down using `float` literals explicitly and correctly.

Comment: *"output differs between two versions."*. I got same output [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15f69d8395dff777)...

Comment: *Does `auto` keyword always evaluates `float` value as `double`?*  **No**, `auto` **never** evaluates `float` values as `double`; `auto` only evaluates `double` values as `double`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that your code is using `::sin` instead of `std::sin` (and the same for `cos`). That is, you’re using the `sin` function found in the global namespace.

`std::sin` is overloaded for `float`. But `::sin` isn’t, and it always returns a `double` (because `::sin` is the legacy C function, and C doesn’t have function overloading).

Use `std::sin` and `std::cos` in your code to fix the issue.

Comment: That's interesting. Without specifying `using namespace std;` and including only `cmath`, ADL is still choosing `std::sin` when resolving `sin` on my clang implementation. I'm genuinely curious how that is happening, as based on what you're saying, it prevents me from replicating the OPs problem (and I suspect I'm not the only one).

Comment: @WhozCraig, No ADL here since there's no `std` type involved. It could be defining `std::sin` and then `using std::sin;` in the global namespace since you'd be doing `#include <math.h>` to get the C one specifically.

Comment: @WhozCraig Like Chris said, this isn’t due to ADL but rather due to the fact that libc++ doesn’t correctly namespace the C++ functions. I *think* this is a bug in the implementation (IIRC because libc++ implements the legacy C headers in terms of the C++ ones, rather than the other way round).

Comment: That would make sense. Sorry about the ADL ref. super tired and waiting on a build before crashing. Does the same thing for `round`, btw, if I strip the `std::` spec. Still pulls in the `std` function. So that drilled-in habit of always prefacing standard lib functions with `std::` in C++ no matter what finally pays off. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the literal `2.5f` you are already suggesting that the value is a float.

You'll see that if you try using `2.5` as literal when assigning value to an auto variable, it deduces this as double.

```cpp
auto var1 = 2.5   // deduced as type double
auto var2 = 2.5f  // deduced as type float as suggested in literal
```